# Office 2007: "Save as <old format>" batch conversion

Tags: conversion, batch, microsoft-office-2007, processing, format

Is there something I can give a "novice user" to convert all Office 2007 documents in a folder to a previosu format?

Comment: Which specific application? I feel a macro coming on...

Comment: There are some formatting information unique to 2007 formats such that if you downconvert, it may cause shifts in appearance.  The other thing is supposedly the 2007 formats are more secure and don't have as many flaws for malware to get a hold of.  That said, a simple google search shows several sites that have converters - some free, some for sale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you could give them the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466&displaylang=en) so they could open Office 2007 documents in Office XP and 2003.

Comment: That looks good! We'll try...